# Samsung-TV Tizen web-app not loading in 2015 devices

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I have submitted a Tizen smart-TV application to the Samsung store, and during the testing process they found that it doesn't start when installed in 2015 devices (it works in modern TVs).

The application was developed in Tizen Studio with TV SDK 4.0, and the minimum compatible platform version is set in the config.xml to Tizen 2.3 (both values apparently compliant with [this compatibility table](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/specifications/tv-model-groups/)).

Samsung's feedback is the same for 15TV_STANDARD1, 15TV_STANDARD2, and 15TV_PREMIUM model groups: *"Blank screen on launching the app."*

Any clue about what can be happening with those TV models? Is there any feature that could be causing the crash?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? we have a similar issue on those tvs.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information is difficult to know what may cause the problem with 2015 TVs.

Your best option would be to debug your application on a 2015 model, although I understand this can be difficult.

One thing you can do is to check the [Web Engine Specifications](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/specifications/web-engine-specifications) and see the differences between the working and non-working models.

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen most likely just means, that your application died somewhere during the initialization.

Did you by any chance use the `getDuid()` API during initial application initialization? I has some trouble with that if the display has never been connected to the web, so it threw an exception on that call.

Otherwise, assuming the profile is indeed 2.3, then it should work.